# Download Zimbra webdav files with spaces

Tags: curl, webdav, zimbra

Zimbra allows to download files via webdav. Unfortunately files with spaces in the name only give empty files back.

How do I have to escape the spaces correctly?

```
curl --basic -k --user user1:password https://server.com/dav/user1/attachments/by-type/text/today/file\ with\ spaces.ics --output calendar.ics   <--- empty
curl --basic -k --user user1:password "https://server.com/dav/user1/attachments/by-type/text/today/file with spaces.ics" --output calendar.ics   <--- empty
curl --basic -k --user user1:password https://server.com/dav/user1/attachments/by-type/text/today/file%20with%20spaces.ics --output calendar.ics   <--- empty
```

This works:

```
curl --basic -k --user user1:password https://server.com/dav/user1/attachments/by-type/text/today/file_without_spaces.ics --output calendar.ics   <-- correct file
```

The server is a Zimbra 8.0.9. I hope it's not a bug of this older version cause updating is no option.

Comment: try using `+` instead of `%20`, still empty? (but if using + actually fix the issue, then it's indeed a bug)

Comment: Unfortunately the same with + . But what I found out it that it's not an empty file as result but a HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found. The empty file is simply made by curl... Anyway - still the same problem.

Comment: What is strange and maybe a hint: when I locally mount the webdav, the files look like this:

`user1@host:~$ ls -la mount_point/attachments/by-type/text/today/
total 189
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    152 Apr 18 12:34  .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root    216 Apr 18 12:34  ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 191068 Apr 18 12:18 'file with spaces.ics'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 191068 Apr 18 12:22  file_without_spaces.ics`